# SUMO TraCi : How to assign the getwaitingtime() of a VehId and add that total Waiting time per lane?

Tags: python, sumo, traffic-simulation

I wanted to get the waiting time of vehicles in SUMO and work it into the TraCI interface. For example I want to receive the  getwaitingtime() of each vehicle Id within a certain area of the network.(meaning they are stopped or waiting in a queue). Then I want to add the total waiting time of Vehicles based on lane or each direction. After the total Time is added I want to assign this value to lets say X. and Use the value of X to perform some mathematical calculations and give decision to change the traffic light.

getwaitingtime(). VehID().

Answer (score 0):

When the vehicle is stopped it doesn't accumulate *waiting time*. Rather you can do this check using `isStopped` command. This will return `True` for each simulation step the vehicle is **stopped** or is in a **stopped state**.

As for the accumulation of waiting time, the waiting time counter is set to 0 each time the vehicle's speed is **greater than 0.1 ms**. So `getWaitingTime` might not give you an accurate measure of the total waiting time for a single vehicle. Use `getAccumulatedWaitingTime` to get the accumulated waiting time for the pre-defined or user-defined `waiting time memory`. This accumulated waiting time can be tested against the simulation time steps (aggregate) and then you can know for sure if the vehicle has been in the queue for a long time or not.

Comment: Thanks. I am really new to SUMO and Traci so i dont have much idea. How would one create a variable that stores these accumulated waiting time for each vehicle?

Comment: @SaurabhBikramBasnet Hello! Just create a variable in python and keep adding to it the value received from the `getAccumulatedWaitingTime` function. It is fairly starightforward. Any python tutorial will give you this solution. Hope this helps